# Laravel query for search

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I want to use this code in Laravel 5.6. I have converted it in Laravel but it is not working.

```php
$location = $filters['location'];
$keywords = $filters['keywords'];
$lst = listing::whereRaw('find_in_set(?,country_id)', [$cid])
    ->where(function ($lst) use ($location) {
        $lst->orWhere('state', '=', $location);
        $lst->orWhere('city', '=', $location);
    })
    ->where(function ($lst) use ($keywords) {
        $lst->where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$keywords.'%');
        $lst->orWhere('listing_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$keywords.'%');
    })
    ->paginate(20);
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM tablename 
    WHERE (field1 = 1 
        AND (field2 = 32 or field3 = 8) 
        AND (field4 LIKE "%6562%" 
        OR field5 LIKE "%6562%"))
```

I'm getting a blank result yet no error message.

Comment: Hey have you tried running this on the database itself using for example ssms, mysql workbench etc? Are you getting a blank result there aswell? If so its the query thats wrong and not the laravel code, this would be nice to know.

Comment: Please install laravel-debugbar or Laravel Telescope to know what query is running. Or you can also run $lst->toSql() to get the query.